# Visual Studio: How can I disable the blue blocks surrounding my blocks of SQL?

Tags: sql, visual-studio, visual-studio-2005

Recently had to install Visual Studio on a new machine and when I open up my SQL scripts the editor is placing these blue lines around blocks of code.  When the mouse hovers over these lines, text appears stating:

This is a block of SQL text.
You can modify this block with Query Builder
by choosing 'Design SQL Block' from the shortcut menu.

Finding this to be a nuisance and I can't seem to find any way to disable it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In VS2005...

Tools -> Options -> Database Tools -> General ... uncheck "Enable DML markers". You'll need to close and reopen any sql scripts you have open that have the DML markers

Answer (score 0):

If you'd rather keep the borders, but alter the color, the setting is the `SQL DML Marker` forecolor, under Text Editor, in Fonts and Colors:

`Tools menu -> Options menu -> Environment section -> Fonts and Colors`